# Take the name that appears while setting an hyperlink with vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint

When you want to add an hyperlink in powerpoint you can access to it for example with right click in the shape that you want and selecting "Hyperlink...". Then appears this dialog box:

[image]

As you can see there appears the slide names but those slides numbers are not the same that you can get with ActivePresentation.Slides(sliNum).Name. How can I get those names with VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seams to be slide index and title shape text or slide name if title not found:

```
Function SlideTitle(ByVal Slide As Slide) As String
    If Slide.Shapes.HasTitle Then
         SlideTitle = Slide.SlideIndex & ". " & Slide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    Else
         SlideTitle = Slide.SlideIndex & ". " & Slide.Name
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
?ActivePresentation.Slides(75).Shapes.Title.Textframe.TextRange.Text
```

Should return **Marketing Plan Overview** in your case